# Como guardo nombre de las imagenes en una BD Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, imagen

Me podrian ayudar con esto ?

Tengo un formulario en html con 3 inputs para cargar fotos, funciona perfecto pero ahora quiero guardar los nombres de las imagenes subidas en una bd (cuando subo estas imagenes son renombradas sin perder su extension) y mi peticion es si me podrian ayudar con el codigo para insertarlas en una "fila" de mi tabla "Jugador", ya he intentado guardarlas pero no se como extraer los nuevos nombres para despues guardarlas, no se como almacenarlas en un variable

PD: las imagenes pueden ser jpg , png o diferentes extensiones, y tiene que guardar con su extension, no es necesario subir las 3 imagenes a veces solo se suben 2 o 1

```
TABLA JUGADOR
---------------------------------------------------------
| id | nombre | apellidos | foto1 | foto2 | foto3 |
--------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | juan   | perez     |ac.jpg | xd.png| asd.gif|
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Código PHP

```
<?php

include ('conexion.php');

function generarCodigo($longitud) { 
    $key = '';  
    $pattern = '1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';  
    $max = strlen($pattern)-1;  
    for ($i=0;$i < $longitud;$i++) $key .= $pattern{
        mt_rand(0,$max)
    };  
    return $key;    
}


$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png","JPG","jpeg","JPEG","PNG","gif");

$max_file_size = 1024*1000;
//100 kb
$path = "images/";
// Upload directory
$count = 0;

$letragenerada = generarCodigo(6);
$random=rand(1,10);

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

    //  Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['userImage']['name'] as $f => $name) { 
        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['userImage']['name'][$f], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);      
        $lid= $letragenerada."".$random.".".$ext;

        if ($_FILES['userImage']['error'][$f] == 4) {           
            continue;
            //          Skip file if any error found
        }       

        if ($_FILES['userImage']['error'][$f] == 0) {           

            if ($_FILES['userImage']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {                
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";                
                continue;
                //              Skip large files
            }

            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){              
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";             
                continue;
                //              Skip invalid file formats
            }           
            else{
                //              No error found! Move uploaded files 
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userImage"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$lid))
                $count++;
                //              Number of successfully uploaded file                
            }           
        }   
    }   
    //  Supongo que aqui estaria el codigo para insertar, no se como poner los nombres en values !



$imagenes = implode(",",$_FILES['userImage']['name']);
$array = explode(",", $imagenes);

                    $Sql="insert into jugador (imagen1,imagen2,imagen3) values(
                            '".$array[0]."',
                            '".$array[1]."',
                            '".$array[2]."')";



                    mysql_query($Sql);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: agregue codigo para insertar a la bd, pero solo me inserta con el nombre de origen del archivo, y no con el nuevo nombre generado por la variable "$lid" que es lo que yo estoy buscando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que está sucediendo, es que en el momento de mover la foto al directorio la estas re nombrando. Para solucionar tu problema de guardar el dato en la base de datos lo puedes hacer de dos forma:

> 1. Manteniendo el mismo nombre con que se sube la imagen.

```
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    $i = 0; 
    //  Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['userImage']['name'] as $f => $name) { 

        $lid= $_FILES['userImage']['name'][$f];

        $array[$i]= $lid;

        if ($_FILES['userImage']['error'][$f] == 4) {           
            continue;
            //          Skip file if any error found
        }       

        if ($_FILES['userImage']['error'][$f] == 0) {           

            if ($_FILES['userImage']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {                
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";                
                continue;
                //              Skip large files
            }

            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){              
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";             
                continue;
                //              Skip invalid file formats
            }           
            else{
                //              No error found! Move uploaded files 
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userImage"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$lid))
                $count++;
                //              Number of successfully uploaded file                
            } 
           $i++          
        }   
    }
```

> En el Insert seria

```
            $Sql="insert into jugador (imagen1,imagen2,imagen3) values(
                    '".$array[0]."',
                    '".$array[1]."',
                    '".$array[2]."')";



            mysql_query($Sql);
```

> 2. Colocando el nombre renombrado en la base de datos:

```
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    $i = 0;
    //  Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['userImage']['name'] as $f => $name) { 
        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['userImage']['name'][$f], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);      
        $lid= $letragenerada."".$random.".".$ext;

        $array[$i]= $lid;

        if ($_FILES['userImage']['error'][$f] == 4) {           
            continue;
            //          Skip file if any error found
        }       

        if ($_FILES['userImage']['error'][$f] == 0) {           

            if ($_FILES['userImage']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {                
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";                
                continue;
                //              Skip large files
            }

            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){              
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";             
                continue;
                //              Skip invalid file formats
            }           
            else{
                //              No error found! Move uploaded files 
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userImage"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$lid))
                $count++;
                //              Number of successfully uploaded file                
            }  
          $i++;         
        }   
    }
```

> El Insert 2

```
        $Sql="insert into jugador (imagen1,imagen2,imagen3) values(
                '".$array[0]."',
                '".$array[1]."',
                '".$array[2]."')";



        mysql_query($Sql);
```